# Wordpress File handle - fopen, fwrite not working with $.ajax or $.post Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, fopen

I am making some log for all the action done in the site that can be store in a .txt file.

my php code in working fine when doing a normal load, but when i use ajax it seems like i doesn't read the fopen, fpost method on php..

please check my code.

This is my function and ajax handler

```
function action_log( $msg ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $path = "wp-content/themes/creation/templates/inc/log.txt";
    $myfile = (file_exists($path)) ? fopen($path, "a+") : fopen($path, "w+");
    $txt = $msg.$current_user->display_name."\n";

    if ( $myfile ) {
        fwrite( $myfile, $txt );
        fclose( $myfile );
        chmod($path, 0777);
        $result = $txt;
        return $result;
    } else {
        $result = $myfile;
        return $txt;
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_action-log-ajax', 'action_log_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_action-log-ajax', 'action_log_ajax');
function action_log_ajax(){

    $post = $_REQUEST;
    $msg = $post['msg'];
    $write = action_log( $msg );

    exit( wp_send_json_success( $write ) );
}
```

My jquery plugin function

```
  $.send_log_changes = function( $msg ) {

    var msgs = $msg;
    var action = 'action-log-ajax';
    console.log(msgs);

    $.post({
      url: plugins_ajax.ajaxUrl,
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        action: action,
        msg: msgs
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function( respones ) {
        console.log(respones);
      }

    });
 }
```

I tried using .ajax, .get, .post and still the same error.
it always return in `False`and cant write/open in the file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the file open operation is returning false. Have you tried entering full path in $path variable i.e. /var/www/html/demo/wp-content/themes/creation/templates/inc/log.txt" etc,.

Comment: there is no problem with the path. the path is working when the site is fully loaded, but with ajax it is not working.. and also i tried that full path and same result.. anyways thanks for the answer, still looking for a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hate to resurrect this, but was having a similar problem in production after it was working fine in dev. Turns out, SELinux was enabled in prod and was blocking the file creation from `fopen()`. Once disabled, it worked just fine.